# Does Adobe Dreamweaver support Javascript?

Tags: html, javascript, dreamweaver

Thinking of subscribing to Adobe Creative Cloud. Does Adobe Dreamweaver support Javascript?

Comment: Considering that Adobe [wrote an Ajax framework](https://github.com/adobe/Spry) I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: No I'm kidding, I used Dreamweaver for several years and I can tell you that it definitely does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, it's a normal code editor. Every code editor supports it, you can write Javascript with Notepad if you want to.

Dreamweaver has an autocomplete for Javascript function so that could be interesting for you... But it's not a must.

Comment: I believe when he says "support" he means autocomplete and other such features, and not just the ability to read and edit JavaScript code.

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't. Although you can write code it in, it just has the ability to read and edit the code. I would recommend other text editors for editing code like Notepad++ for Windows and Sublime Text for Mac